# Does it make sense to create entity table with only ID attribute?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Does it make sense to create a single entity when it should only contain the `@Id` value as a String?

```
@Entity
class CountryCode {
   @Id
   String letterCode; //GBR, FRA, etc
}

@Entity
class Payment {
   CountryCode code;
   // or directly without further table: String countryCode;
}
```

Or would you just use the letterCode as the stringvalue instead of creating the `CountryCode` entity?

It should later be possible for example to fetch all payments that contain a specific countrycode. This might be possible with both solutions. But which is the better one (why)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can if you are using the entity as a lookup. In your example, you may want to add a column for description congaing (France, Great Britain, etc.) for the letter code and a third column whether it is active or not and maybe columns for when inserted and when it was last changed.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to create such table to provide consistency of data, that is that no `Payment` is created with non-existing `CountryCode`. Having a separate entity (that is table) together with foreign key on `Payment` allows checking for consistency in database.

Another possible approach is to have check constraint on the code field but this is error prone if codes are added/deleted and/or there are more than one column of this type.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `letterCode` the the `Payment` Class as String Attribute (Or Enum to prevent typo errors) will increase the fetch performance as you do not need to create a join over your `CountryCode` Table.